# Json JQ Filter with Wildcard in Bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

Json input:

```
[ "orange-1234", "orange-12345", "apple-1234" ]
```

Desired output:

```
[ "orange-1234, "orange-12345" ]
```

Via bash, I would like to use jq to find the values starting or containing orange*

I would like the output to contain the complete value.  I have explored using jq startswith and contains, but only was able to return true or false

Answer (score 3):

As of jq 1.5, you could do regular expression matching.  So with that, just filter your array.

```
map(select(test("\\borange\\b")))
```

Comment: jq map(select(test("\\borange\\b"))) I get bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: _Always_ put the filter in (single) quotes. Make sure it's in the form: `jq 'map(select(test("\\borange\\b")))'`

Comment: jq -c '. - map(select(test("\\orange\\b")))' produces the opposite...["apple-1234"]

Answer (score 2):

`startswith` and `contains` can do this just fine. Use `select` to filter values by true/false:

```
map(select(startswith("orange")))
```

Comment: what is map doing here?

Answer (score 0):

if you run this command :-

echo '[ "orange-1234", "orange-12345", "apple-1234" ]' | jq 'map(select(test(orange)))'

you get the following output :

[ "orange-1234", "orange-12345" ]

here map expects a function which helps in filtering the elements, so here jq is essentially iterating over all elements, and selecting only those which return true for test(orange), which is a regex check